# How to add expandable ListView's child item without duplicate object data listheader

Tags: android, list, duplicates, expandablelistview

I have a problem in Android. I have a list. For example name is list;
ListModel has a id,name ..

And my data is,

```
list.get(0).getName(); // name = A
list.get(0).getId(); // id = 1
list.get(1).getName(); // name = B
list.get(1).getId(); // id = 2
list.get(2).getName(); // name = C
list.get(2).getId(); // id = 3
list.get(3).getName(); // name = A
list.get(3).getId(); // id = 4
list.get(4).getName(); // name = B
list.get(4).getId(); // id = 5
```

So I want to use this data in expandableListView in Android. But without duplicate name. It means I want to show just A,B,C and when I click the A, I wanna see all A's id in childs.. For example is ;

```
A -->1,4
B -->2,5
C -->3
```

How can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
// This is your data
ArrayList<ListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ListModel("A", "1"));
list.add(new ListModel("B", "2"));
list.add(new ListModel("C", "3"));
list.add(new ListModel("A", "4"));
list.add(new ListModel("B", "5"));

// Create a list of keys (A, B, C)
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
for (ListModel item : list) {
    keys.add(item.getName());
}

// The final dataset
Map<String, List<String>> dataset = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : keys) {
    List<String> subItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ListModel item : list) {
        if(item.getName().equals(key)){
            subItems.add(item.getId());
        }
    }
    dataset.put(key, subItems);
}
Log.e(TAG, dataset.toString());
```

If anyone has a better solution please share.